# MySQL and express.socket.io-session, variables outside of function

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Updated code to show what I have done. I am having trouble grabbing specific information from `.session.userdata`

```
// Socket stuff
io.use(sharedsession(session));
io.on('connect', function (socket) {
    var str = JSON.stringify(socket.handshake.session.passport);
    str = JSON.stringify(socket.handshake.session.passport, null, 4);

    // console.log(str);
    var query = db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', socket.handshake.session.passport.user, function (err, row) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      } else {
        console.log(row) // added 
        socket.handshake.session.userdata = row;
        socket.handshake.session.save();
        var dataObj = socket.handshake.session.userdata;
        socket.emit('startup', dataObj);
      }
    });

    // Server Time
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var momentNow = moment();
        var data = momentNow.format('LT');
        socket.emit('time', data);
      }, 60000);

    // Chat - Needs work
    socket.on('chat', function (msg) {
      console.log(socket.handshake.session.userdata.username);
      var message = msg;

      // username = req.user.username;
      io.emit('message', message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      if (socket.handshake.session.userdata) {
        delete socket.handshake.session.userdata;
        socket.handshake.session.save();
      }

      console.log('user disconnected');
    });

  });
```

I added a console log for row itself heres the data packet:

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 3,
    username: 'test',
    password: '$2a$10$BGKL6fyTbZ3bwVCfSmj3Iu6OGBAryV.qkDNeHsRD/enCbldCW.PuC',
    email: 'test@test.test',
    rank: 1,
    title: 'Squire',
    kills: 0,
    deaths: 0,
    medals: 0,
    silver: 100,
    kingname: 'test',
    str: 5,
    tough: 5,
    speed: 5,
    accur: 5,
    farmlevel: 1,
    food: 0,
    minelevel: 1,
    iron: 0,
    stonelevel: 1,
    stone: 0,
    lumberlevel: 1,
    lumber: 0 } ]
```

Comment: Your second `console.log(socket.handshake.session.userdata);` is BEFORE the query completes.  The query is asynchronous.  It completes some undetermined time in the future while the rest of your Javascript continues to run.  The ONLY place to use the results of the query is INSIDE the query callback or in some event that you are sure happens after the query has finished.

Comment: Yup! I figured that out, thanks though :). However... still having issues using the data in any way though. I can't seem to call the data othan than in a complete row. I'm probably missing a very nooby thing, but I'm pretty tired.

Comment: Okay so I'm still trying to figure out why I can;t access the data directly. All it will let me do is print out a raw row data. I can't do `socket.handshake.session.userdata.id` or anythings that is in the actual row. If I do it returns as undefined. Why is this the case?

Comment: You may have to save data to the session after modifying it.

Comment: I did. I added a `socket.handshake.session.save()` after defining it. Still nothing. It prints the row still but nothing else. I have a chat emitter, and it does it fine, but once i try to get specific, like username or id it goes to undefined. It pulls up the right row because I have it go into the console on chat sending and i used multiple accounts. Givem me bout 30 minutes and ill updaye OP with my newest code.

Comment: Okay updated OP to show what I have done. You can ignore the dataObj variable I have done.

Comment: So, with this new version of the code, what exactly is the problem?  What doesn't show and where?  Which exact `console.log()` statement doesn't show what you expect?  What does it show?  What should it show?  Did you verify that the info you expect was in the original `row` that you put into the session?

Comment: FYI, `if (err) throw err` is not valid error handling in an async callback.  It does nothing useful.

Comment: This: `console.log(socket.handshake.session.userdata.username);` show as undefined. It should, well... show my username. (or who ever sends the message at this point under the `// chat - needs work` comment. As you can imagine, I haven't touched error handling, so I use that just because. But it works fine, at least defining of the row, because taking off `.username` it'll show the whole row of whoever sent the message.

Comment: If you put `console.log(socket.handshake.session.userdata.username);` on the line right after `socket.emit('startup', dataObj);` do you see the username there?

Comment: Nope. It is undefined everywhere. However just using `socket.handshake.session.userdata` works correctly. I've tested it on multiple connections and accounts and it displays the row correctly.

Comment: If it doesn't work where I asked you to test it right after you queried it, then it won't work anywhere else.  So, the issue is somehow with the userdata object itself.  I'd probably have to see the userdata object in the debugger myself to have any further ideas.  You don't say what database you're using.  Do you have to do anything special with the `row` object in order to turn it into a full-fledged Javascript object as opposed to some sort of special database object?

Comment: I'm using MariaDB with passport login. As far as I know, I do not need to do anything special (I have another table defined, although out of the socket connection and it works fine this way). I can show you what the row returns in my console, but not in comments.

Comment: If you can add `console.log(row)` to the end of your question, I'll take a look.  Is it by any chance an array of results, not just a single result?

Comment: Alright, added inside my question. Thanks for all the help, by the way.

Comment: It's an array of data.  If you want the first element, you have to index it to get it.  Change this `socket.handshake.session.userdata = row;` to this `socket.handshake.session.userdata = row[0];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `row` variable is an array, not a single value.  You need to index into that array to get a single userData object.

Change this:

```
socket.handshake.session.userdata = row;
```

to this:

```
socket.handshake.session.userdata = row[0];
```

You may need to check the length of the array to make sure it's not empty (that depends upon how your DB behaves when the query doesn't find any data).

Comment: I really hate myself right now. I can't believe I forgot something so simple. 8 hours of stupid work and something so simple. Gotta hate to love coding I guess. Thank you!

Comment: @William - That's life with coding.  Sometimes the obvious thing escapes you for far too long.  Anyway, glad we figured it out.